# Literature study for Optimal Estimation Theory

Tags: reference-request, optimization, control-theory, parameter-estimation

It seems Optimal Estimation/Control Theory requires a lot more than undergraduate maths. Any good book that would help me get started?

I have so far referred the following books but found them quite difficult. Is it just me? is it the subject? or are there better books? Extra points for someone who gives a detailed road map of how to go about learning Optimal Estimation/Control Theory

[H.W Sorenson - Parameter Estimation](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Parameter_estimation.html?id=80kZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

[Dan Simon - Optimal Estimation Theory](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Optimal_State_Estimation.html?id=urhgTdd8bNUC&redir_esc=y)

[Arthur Gelb - Applied Optimal Estimation](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Applied_Optimal_Estimation.html?id=KlFrn8lpPP0C&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Maybe the last two college slides of this lecture will help you, http://www.eng.newcastle.edu.au/~jhb519/teaching/elec4410/docs.html

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are a mathematician interested in the calculus of variations approach, before going into optimal control and estimation I'd start with a more introductory and less specialized text on classical control such as

Feedback Systems
An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers
Karl Johan Åström Richard M. Murray

There are many other good textbooks for a intro classical control course, it's a question of preference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Estimation theory goes, for the start I would suggest Steven Kay's two volumes on Statistical Signal Processing. In my opinion that is the most gentle introduction to the subject.

After reading those two books and solving as many of problems as you can, you can hop on to any of the following standard (my personal favorite) texts:

1. Parameter Estimation by Bernard Levy
2. Detection, Estimation and Modulation Theory (1st volume), by Van Trees
3. Statistical Signal Processing by Scharf.

Some neat estimation and inference ideas like graphical models are discussed in Chris Bishop's machine learning text as well. I learned a lot of inference from that book.